# jquery: change div text

Tags: jquery, text, html

I want to update the text of a div tag; I first get the owner of this div by using:

```
var yTickLabels = $("#flotDiv").find(".yAxis >div");
```

by using firebug, i can see two children div nodes are obtained in [yTickLabels], then I use following codes to update the text of each children div node:

```
for(var i=0; i<yTickLabels.length;i++){
    yTickLabels[i].update("new text");
}
```

however, above codes failed with error "update is not a function"; then I tried using html() or text() to retrive current text, still failed.

in the output html, these divs are displayed as follows:

```
<div class="yAxis y1Axis" style="color:rgb(0, 0, 0)">
    <div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:115px;right:836px;width:0px">
       <b>Pavement-Type</b>
    </div>
    <div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:178px;right:836px;width:0px">
       <b>PCC</b>
    </div>
 </div>
```

in which way I should employ to update the text of each [div] with [yAxis] class? Thanks all!

Comment: did you find any div under #flotDiv ? there is no id named floatDiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over a jQuery Array in such a way, you're returning the actual DOM element, not the jQuery element, so it doesn't have access to jQuery functions. You need to use `.each()` to keep it local to jQuery, or reevaluate the element by wrapping it in `$(element)`.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 3):

The error message is correct, update is not a function.

Instead of this:

```
for(var i=0; i<yTickLabels.length;i++){
    yTickLabels[i].update("new text");
}
```

use jquery, like so:

```
yTickLabels.each(function(){
  $(this).text("new text");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because update() is in fact not a function. Try updating it to this

```
for(var i=0; i<yTickLabels.length;i++){
    $(yTickLabels[i]).text("new text");
}
```

Comment: This won't work, `$('selector')[0]` will return the actual DOM element, which more than likely won't have the method `.text()`

Answer (score 1):

JQuery provides the each function:
http://api.jquery.com/each/

try:

$("#flotDiv").find(".yAxis >div").each(function(index) {
    $(this).update("new text");
  });